# Why isBinarySearchTree() function is not correct

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am checking if a tree is a binary search tree. I see what the known solution is. Prior to me looking it up, I came up with the following attempt based off of post order traversal. I have traced it by hand, and seems to make sense. But, it is incorrect. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
 }

boolean checkBST(Node root) {

    // Empty tree
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }

    // Sub trees are BST
    boolean valid = checkBST(root.left) && checkBST(root.right);     

    // Greater than left
    if (root.left != null) {
        valid = valid && root.data > root.left.data;
    }

    // Less than right
    if (root.right != null) {
        valid = valid && root.data < root.right.data;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I hope you see the mistake now.

Comment: @Nelxiost It's most likely java (note the `boolean` keyword).

Comment: @Nelxiost sorry, it is Java! I was doing this on Hackerrank. And it was a code stub, so I forgot to paste the language, or put it into a class file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will fail for this basic test case,as it returns true for following:

```
    50 
   /
  3
 / \
1   100
```

The problem is your code is only comparing the node with its immediate children and not with the entire subtree. It return true for **subtree rooted at 3** and 
 because **3 < 50**, your code finally returns true, which is wrong.